# Flutter: How to add a button More in ListView

Tags: flutter, dart

How to make the "More" button appear after 10 elements. It turns out after each 10 elements, the "More" button appeared.
Also, how can I write the date format so that it appears (Day, Month, Year) in the line $ {data [index] ['VTime']}.
And is this code correct or not?

Advise something thanks

You can see the code here.
[enter link description here](https://github.com/akbarsulaymonov/main.dart/blob/master/main.dart)

Answer (score 0):

For showing a `more` button after every 10th element you can append a more button to original element by adding a condition to the element.

Call below shown widget from your `ListView.builder()` Widget

```
Widget yourWidget(int index){
   return Column(
             children: <Widget>[
                  yourViewWidget(),
                  index % 10 == 0 ? moreButton() : SizedBox()        
             ]
          );
}
```

what this function will do is if the `index % 10 == 0` then will show more button as you asked.

and regarding the `DateTime()`

You can use DateFormat from [intl](https://pub.dev/packages/intl) package.

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat("dd, MM, yyyy");
//Converting String to DateTime object
DateTime dateTime = dateFormat.parse("2019-07-19 8:40:23");
```